# PURE CSS3 slide up, down, left, right transitions without animate.css

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am building a text-only menu (client requirement) as some of their clients will need to navigate without JS turned on. The menu works for all intended purposes but I wanted to "beautify" it a little by adding CSS3 transitions to the way the menu dropdowns on hover and flies out to the right on 3rd levels (also on hover).

My attempts have been to apply the following to the `<ul>` that will take the action

```
.mymenu ul li:hover ul {
   opacity: 1;
   height: auto;
   overflow: visible;
   width: auto;  
   min-width: 190px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   }
```

That doesn't do anything (or I wouldn't be here, now would I? lol)

Essentially, I would like someone to solve this for me and **explain it** if possible. Don't rush on answering quickly to miss the question answered checkmark. I will check it for sure :)

I need an animated dropdown effect but a non-animated close of the dropdown so that it can keep up withe the user's speed. And the same effect but left-right on the 3rd level submenus

I have created a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbPdEE) for you.

If you want a better idea of what I am looking for, you can see the LinkedIn menu and you will see the dropdown effect there as well.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: [something like this?](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/OPOmmB) - no JS, just pure Css

Comment: @jbutler That was a very good start. I like that you took the initiative to make a fade instead of a dropdown, not what I asked, but I am willing to accept it! Good on ya bud! Now, the width is sliding. That has to remain fixed. If you hover over the career tools menu item, the menu in it must slide to the right or even fade. Thanks

Comment: constructing an explained answer presently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you're using `display` to show/hide your menus + sub menus. This isn't working *since* they're like a boolean value: **on or off** - i.e. there isn't an 'intermediate' value for you to choose.

---

So, what's a possible solution? Well, I've replaced your use of `display:`, and changed it to `opacity:` instead, which *does* have intermediate values, and hence *can* be transitioned nicely.

So, the basics are:

- replace `display: none` to `opacity:0`
- replace `display: inline` to `opacity:1`

---

**Demo**

```css
.mymenu {
  background: #0067A5;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 17px #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  height: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #0067A5;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 17px #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  width: 570px;
  margin-left: 425px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}
li.retrodropdown {
  height: 50px;
}
.mymenu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 18px 0px 8px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: open sans !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.mymenu .retrodropdown-menu {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  top: 32px;
  left: 4px;
}
.retrodropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.retrodropdown:hover .retrodropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
.retrodropdown-menu li {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0871A;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mymenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.mymenu ul li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
}
.mymenu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 192px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 155px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.retrodropdown-menu li:not(.header):hover,
.jg-header-navigation .retrodropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #0067A5;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
.mymenu ul li ul {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 190px;
}
.mymenu ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="mymenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="retrodropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
      <a id="RetroHeader_HyperLink7">Career Services</a>
      <ul class="retrodropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume Help</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Promote Yourself</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flyout-menu"><a href="#">Career Tools</a>
          <ul class="fadeInLeft animated">
            <li><a href="#">Skills Assessment</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Career Videos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Career Exploration</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Interview Training</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Military Translator</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

Flyout [demo](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/OPOmmB) - IMO not as nice looking as fade

This works by setting the width to 0 normally, and then altering this on the hover. the use of the transition allows for this to be animated.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. However the width of the dropdown is animating. I need that to remain fixed. Is this caused by the code you added or by something I had previously in it? Also, I am happy with the fade dropdown, but I still think the flyout should be a slide to right animation. Any chance you would be able to do that?

Comment: just updated for width being fixed. I have to say, there was a fair bit of redundant code in there (and still is a bit).

Comment: @LOTUSMS: undated codepen demo should be that 'flyout' for you.